# creating a collection view for data obtained

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am looking to do something like the attached image

Firstly a collection view that will show everyday's date, and when you tap on a specific date, it will show data that was collected from the user's input elsewhere. The page will not appear immediately after the input, but the data will be collected so the user can reference later (healthcare app)

Would need some general help about how to do it, I can try to google the codes elsewhere

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLg9X.jpg]

Comment: user3427951 tapping on the specific day you want to show another page with user entered data for that day, isn't it?

Comment: yes. but i want these boxes to be created everyday, even if no data is entered for that day.

Comment: for a whole month or just a week?

Comment: for a week should be sufficient

Comment: arunvmadav is my skypeid, if you can go for a chat